# pgfplots axis descriptions from file

Tags: pgfplots, labels

I was wondering if there is any way to make pgfplots read the xlabel and ylabel from a file.
This is similar to this question [Using Labels from a File in PGFplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21220/using-labels-from-a-file-in-pgfplot) but I'd like to read the column headings and use them as axis descriptions (not as labels for individual ticks).

To stick with the example from the other post, for a file foo.dat like this

```
# foo.dat
# X-Position Height
  1          15
  2          20
  3          12
  4          24
```

I would like to have an axis environment equivalent to

```
\begin{axis}[xlabel=X-Position, ylabel=Height]
   \addplot file {foo.dat};
\end{axis}
```

but without having to specify `xlabel=X-Position, ylabel=Height` explicitly.

The reason for this strange question is that I'm using a tex file in a script to generate plot images. Without axis descriptions I can generate a data file, copy both the data file and the prepared tex file into a temporary folder an compile everything. If what I asked is not possible, I would have to change the tex file. I can deal with this by generating the tex file on the fly in this case, but I was just wondering if there was a better solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that is possible using the macros of `pgfplotstable` (which is always shipped together with `pgfplots`).

`pgfplotstable` allows to read the table into some in-memory structure, and it supports `\pgfplotstableforeachcolumn<\tablename>\as<\loopvariable>{<loop body>}`. Inside of `<loop body>`, the macro `<\loopvariable>` expands to the column name and `\pgfplotstablecol` expands to the column index.

Thus, we can iterate over all columns and have access to name and index. We only need to combine this with a TeX expansion trick and a mapping from column indices to axis directions (0=>x, 1=>y) and have a running prototype:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{foo.dat}
# foo.dat
 X-Position Height
  1          15
  2          20
  3          12
  4          24
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % this here allows to set labels by INDEX rather than 'x', 'y', or 'z':
    \pgfplotsset{
        label no 0/.style={xlabel={#1}},
        label no 1/.style={ylabel={#1}},
        label no 2/.style={zlabel={#1}},
    }
    % this loads your external data file:
    \pgfplotstableread{foo.dat}\loadedtable

    % this iterates over every column name, where the current column name is stored in
    % '\col':
    \pgfplotstableforeachcolumn\loadedtable\as\col{%
        % this here defines '\temp' to be 
        %   '\pgfplotsset{label no 0={X-Position}}'
        % instead of
        %   '\pgfplotsset{label no 0={\col}}'
        % purpose: '\col' must be expanded (\'e'def) immediately
        % before it is overwritten in the next loop iteration.
        \edef\temp{\noexpand\pgfplotsset{label no \pgfplotstablecol={\col}}}
        % this here calls '\temp':
        \temp
    }%

    % the axis always uses the currently set options - in our case
    % 'xlabel' and 'ylabel':
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot table {\loadedtable};  
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that I removed the `#` before your column headings in `foo.dat`: `pgfplotstable` will ignore any data line which starts with `#` (which is considered to be a comment char).

The `<name>/.style={<stuff>}`  syntax is the way of pgf to define a style called `<name>`. Whenever `<name>={<value>}` is used, it expands to the keys `<stuff>` where `#1` is replaced by `<value>`. That's how the mapping from column index to x, y, and z is done.

The remaining tricky part with `\edef` does precisely what I wrote in the source comment - but it is not commonly known. It is some kind of scripting element in TeX (see  `texdoc TeX-programming-Notes` if you want to learn more about TeX's expansion control).

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Maybe a variant of this would make a nice macro for pgfplots. Something like `\plottablecolumns{3}{1}{foo.dat}` could be used to add an axis environment with xlabel=columnheader[3], ylabel=columnheader[1] and exactly one plot that plots columns 3 (as x) and 1 (as y). Would probably need some if-then-else construct to pick the correct columns during the loop. Anyway, that was just a thought, all I needed right now was what you explained in your answer.