# Problem with loop in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to loop through a parameter to produce shifted graphs in grouppplots, as in the following MWE, however the value of `\k` doesn't seem to be recognized in the argument of `sin`, i.e. the black lines are not shifted. I inserted a red line with shift `0.25` manually for comparison. What did I do wrong?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 3},width=\textwidth,height=4cm,xmin=0,xmax=2,samples=200]
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \k in {0,0.25,0.5}{
  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot[domain=0:2] gnuplot {sin(2*pi*(x - \k))} node[above,pos=0.5]{\k};
  \addplot[domain=0:2,red,dashed] gnuplot {sin(2*pi*(x - 0.25))} node[above,pos=0.5]{\k};
}
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the expanding universe! (Yes, these expansion tricks can easily drive one close to madness. ;-))

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 3},width=\textwidth,height=4cm,xmin=0,xmax=2,samples=200]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,0.25,0.5}{
  \nextgroupplot
  \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[domain=0:2] gnuplot {sin(2*pi*(x - #1))}
  node[above,pos=0.5]{#1};}
  \temp
  \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[domain=0:2,red,dashed] gnuplot {sin(2*pi*(x -
  0.25))} node[above,pos=0.5]{#1};}
  \temp
}
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**"EXPLANATION"**: When playing with pgfplots for a while, one comes across some [standard tricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28596/121799) which one applies until one gets the desired result. ;-)