# Dynamic tikz bar plot from JSON data

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart, json

I have JSON file that looks something like this

```
{
    "data": [
    {
        "type": "SENIOR",
        "male": 350000.0,
        "female": 225000.0
    },
    {
        "type": "ENTRY",
        "male": 100000.0,
        "female": 40000.0
    },
    {
        "type": "MID",
        "male": 225000.0,
        "female": 150000.0
    }
    ]
}
```

and I need to create a bar plot with dynamic x fields, that are read from json.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ifthen}

%%%%% Lua code %%%%%%
\begin{luacode}
    local json = require("json")
    local file = io.open("mwe.json")
    tab = json.parse(file:read("*all"))
    file:close()
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
% Number of labels
\newcommand{\nrlabels}{\directlua{tex.print(table.getn(tab['data']))}}

% Create counter for loop through labels
\newcounter{labelctr}\stepcounter{labelctr}
\newcounter{totallabels}
\setcounter{totallabels}{\nrlabels}\stepcounter{totallabels}
\newcounter{onemorelabel}\setcounter{onemorelabel}{\value{totallabels}}\addtocounter{onemorelabel}{-1}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
        height = 8cm,
        %major x tick style = transparent,
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=20pt,
        %ymajorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {Average Wage},
        %symbolic x coords= {\whiledo{\value{labelctr} < \value{totallabels}}{\directlua{tex.print(tab['data'][\thelabelctr]['type'])}\ifthenelse{\value{labelctr}<\value{onemorelabel}}{,}{}\stepcounter{labelctr}}}
        symbolic x coords={SENIOR,ENTRY,MID}
        ]
        \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates {\whiledo{\value{labelctr} < \value{totallabels}}{(\directlua{tex.print(tab['data'][\thelabelctr]['type'])}, \directlua{tex.print(tab['data'][\thelabelctr]['male'])}) \stepcounter{labelctr}}};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

This is what I have so far.
And I need something like this[image]

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining [How to plot data from json](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576669/how-to-plot-data-from-json) and [Comma in x coord (interval)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597981/comma-in-x-coord-interval/598022) gives the MWE below.

The idea is to use `tex.sprint` to write the table in the correct format to the input stream, as if the table data was actually written in the `.tex` file. Then `\pgfplotstableread` can read the entire table at once.

For the plot this requires the options `xticklabels from table` and `xtick=data`. Each category has a separate `\addplot` command with the corresponding `y` index in the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
%%%%% Lua code %%%%%%
%% This prints the following table to the input stream:
%% type male female
%% SENIOR 350000.0 225000.0
%% ENTRY 100000.0 40000.0
%% MID 225000.0 150000.0

\expandafter\pgfplotstableread\directlua{
    local json = utilities.json.load("groupeddata.json")
    tex.sprint("{\string\r")
    tex.sprint("type male female\string\r")
    for n, row in ipairs(json.data) do
        tex.sprint(row.type .. " " .. row.male .. " " .. row.female .. "\string\r")
    end
    tex.sprint("}")
}\loadedtable

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
        height = 8cm,
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        area legend,
        bar width=20pt,
        ylabel = {Average Wage},
        xticklabels from table={\loadedtable}{type},
        xtick = data,
        legend pos=north east,
        ]
        \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=1] {\loadedtable};
        \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=2] {\loadedtable};
        \legend{male,female}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Note that some things are still hardcoded, namely the column headers in the table, the field names in the data rows, the number of categories (with associated `y` values) and the legend. The headers are actually not needed (the category column for the `xticklabels` can be referred by index as well), but this requires the `header=false` option to `\pgfplotstableread` which makes `\expandafter` more complicated. Looping the json array can probably be generalized within the Lua code but for this proof-of-concept answer I didn't look into that. Finally the separate `\addplot table` statements and the legend, this can be done using `\foreach`. See [Use first row of a table as legend entry in pgfplot graph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23993/use-first-row-of-a-table-as-legend-entry-in-pgfplot-graph) for some examples of the remarks above.